# How can I trim whitespace AFTER sentence

Tags: c#, regex, string, whitespace, removing-whitespace

Let's say I have a string that is like this:

```
This is a string-----------------------------
```

Where the - is whitespace that has to be deleted. Only the whitespace after the last word, not the whitespace inbetween the words.

So basicly, how can I trim the above to:

```
This is a string
```

Without whitespace at the end of sentence.

**EDIT:** Notice: This has to be dynamic, since I can't predict what the string will have in it. But it will ALWAYS have alot of whitespaces at the end.

Comment: Are there multiple sentences per string, or just one?

Comment: Just one :) But Joel Coehoorn just answered my question. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string myString = "This is a string-----------------------------";
myString = myString.TrimEnd('-');
```

or if you're just using the `-` character as a placeholder for any whitespace:

```
string myString = "This is a string                     ";
myString = myString.TrimEnd();
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Answer will be accepted, whenever I can.

Answer (score 1):

C# has TrimEnd() method for string.

example usage:

```
String str = "This is a string                             ";
            Console.WriteLine(str.Length); // Returns 45
            str = str.TrimEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(str.Length); // Returns 16
```

If you want to use regex you could use something like `[ \t]+$` to select all whitespaces and tabs at the end of the line. But it seems to me as an overkill - we already have Trim TrimEnd and TrimStart methods :)